# Spring Framework InputStream startup loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have some files which load through InputStream like:

```
InputStream model = new FileInputStream(modelFile);
```

But this process is pretty slow, so I need to load them one time in startup instead of loading when comes request.

I know some ways to do it in .NET MVC like via `Global.asax` or `CacheHelper`, but don't know how to do it in Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how.
Spring has some Initializer class equivalent 'Global.asax', which can contain onStartup method. So for example I want to load my models on startup, I put this code here.

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    try (AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext()) {
        ctx.register(BaseConfiguration.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        try {
            LoadModels();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basicaly, you want to do some intialization once Spring context has finished starting.

One way to do so in Spring is to have one of your Spring managed bean, implements [`InitializingBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html). 
Alternatively, you can also use the standard Java annotation `@PostConstruct` ([JSR-250](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=250)).

Have a look [at the doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-combined-effects) for more detail.